Two files with different contents in the linux overlay file system have the same inode
I'm learning about the linux overlay file system and I'm having a problem that's beyond my knowledge. Can anyone explain the technical rationale behind this?
mkdir ./{merged,work,upper,lower}
echo "message from lower" >> ./lower/h

sudo mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=./lower,upperdir=./upper,workdir=./work ./merged
# copy lower/h on write, and will save to lower/h
echo "message from merged" >> ./merged/h

# check files content: merged/h and upper/h have same content
cat ./lower/h
cat ./merged/h
cat ./upper/h

# this command show merged/h and lower/h have same inode, why isn't upper/h and merged/h have same inode
stat ./lower/h ./upper/h ./merged/h

I think merged/h and upper/h should have the same inode, and lower with different inodes. However, this is not the case with the above experimental results

Before your echo command, merged/h represented lower/h and had the same inum and other metadata as lower/h.
The > merged/h redirection doesn't delete and re-create the file, but merely truncates an existing one, so it causes overlayfs to "copy up" the lower/h file into the writable upper layer; however, merged/h still represents the same file as before which means its inum must not change during the copy-up process – so overlayfs has to continue reporting the original inum even if the file's data is now stored elsewhere.

The experiment appends to merged/h, it doesn’t truncate it.

Inodes aren’t complete identifiers for files on their own, they need to be paired with the device identifier. When I run your experiment, I get this:
  File: ./lower/h
  Size: 19          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fe12h/65042d    Inode: 47198181    Links: 1
[…]
  File: ./upper/h
  Size: 39          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fe12h/65042d    Inode: 47198184    Links: 1
[…]
  File: ./merged/h
  Size: 39          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 4ch/76d Inode: 47198181    Links: 1
[…]

lower/h and upper/h are on the same device (the underlying file system), with different inodes because they’re different files. merged/h is hosted on the overlay, so it has a different device, and the overlay gives it the same inodes as the original underlying file. Appending to a file mustn’t change its inode (it’s still the same file), so merged/h keeps its inode throughout.
